# Three.js outputs whitescreen when importing WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm working on a project for the University, that uses the `three.js` library. I am new to everything related to Computer Graphics, and have started learning this specifically for my course.

I thought that following their own tutorial ([Creating a scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)) might be pretty helpful in building my own perspective on what `three.js` and `WebGL` actually do.

I successfully managed to create a scene with a green cube that rotates itself, based on the code mentioned on the link above.

Basically, I have an `index.html` file that has a `<script>` tag which points to my `main.js` file, that looks like this:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';


const scene  = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const cube     = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// Initiate function or other initializations here
animate();
```

I am using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to start my static server. This is my output:

[image]

The problem comes in the next section of the tutorial, the one related to the [WebGL compatibility check](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/WebGL-compatibility-check). The link attached will redirect you to a tutorial section that features a portion of code containing a check.

I tried updating my `main.js` with one more import (`WebGL`) and a check, before calling the `animate()` function:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

// First Change: importing WebGL
import { WebGL } from 'three/addons/capabilities/WebGL.js';


const scene  = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const cube     = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// Here comes the second change: if statement before calling animate()
if ( WebGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {
    animate();
} else {
    const warning = WebGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( warning );
}
```

The problem is, I'm receiving a white screen right now. Navigating to http://localhost:5173/ doesn't output my rotating green cube anymore. I've realized that deleting the `if` statement doesn't fix anything, the problem being that `import` statement of the `WebGL`. When deleting the `import`, the canvas seems to be output properly again.

Please understand the fact that I am still new to whatever JavaScript and 3D rendering mean, but I am willing to learn.

My question is, what might be the problem that actually causes that white screen?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser developer tools console?